# Handshake failure before server hello

Tags: java, ssl, https, certificate, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to establish a secure connection with an API server, but I get `SSLHandshakeException` after client hello. `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` output is:

```
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
http-bio-8080-exec-10, setSoTimeout(0) called
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1520675917 bytes = { 209, 86, 94, 209, 84, 243, 11, 230, 0, 41, 81, 94, 161, 203, 221, 182, 147, 77, 77, 152, 51, 75, 184, 152, 23, 143, 154, 211 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=test.eu]
***
http-bio-8080-exec-10, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 228
http-bio-8080-exec-10, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
http-bio-8080-exec-10, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
http-bio-8080-exec-10, called closeSocket()
http-bio-8080-exec-10, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
```

And this is the code

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:/Users/Lovro/Desktop/certs/api/test.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "test");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "JKS");
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");

String urlRequest = "https://test.eu/orders/create";
String username = "test";
String password = "test";
String certificatePass = "test";
byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode((username + ":" + password).getBytes());

SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();

URL url = new URL(urlRequest);
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(authEncBytes));
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sslsocketfactory);

conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);

InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
is.close();
```

I don't know where to start or what may be the issue. I tried using the certificate in Postman and it works, I could establish a connection just fine. I didn't add the root authority to my keystore file, I only added the certificate, so don't know if that may be the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it is probably an incompatibility between Client and Server ciphers. Check with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ what protocols and ciphers your server supports

Comment: TLS version seems ok, we both use TLSv1.2 but I see they have RSA 2048 bits for their key. When I was adding my key to .jks keystore, I saw it said subject public key algorithm is 4096-bit RSA key and signature algorithm was SHA512withRSA, whereas it's SHA256withRSA on the server. Is this it, or is the issue with Java code?

Comment: The key size and the algorithm used to sign the certificate is not a problem. Check that the `Cipher Suites:` list sent by your client is supported by the server (at least one cipher)

Comment: Yeah, those don't match up, I suppose that's the issue. Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try another client, such as `openssl s_client` towards this server, and your current client towards another TLS server?

Comment: Just tried with another TLS server, I get a server hello back, and the cipher used is matched (TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256). All available ciphers I have on my client are AES 128bit and this API server supports only AES 256bit. I've got no idea how to enable AES 256bit ciphers in Java, I tried `Security.setProperty("crypto.policy", "unlimited");` but it doesn't seem to be working. My project is using JavaSE-1.8, so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Additionally, just checked and my project is using 1.8.0.u66

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to include new JRE 8u181 instead of 8u66. The older one didn't support AES 256bit ciphers, I think minimal version for those is 8u151, at least that's when `Security.setProperty("crypto.policy", "unlimited");` was included which can be seen [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/release_changes.xml).